# How can I Stop my 2D Character from Gliding After Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am currently making a 2D top down survival game. I have coded the player controller and it works good other than one issue that bugs the crap out of me! My character doesn't stop moving (or decelerates very slowly) whenever I stop pressing the movement keys. How can I make it so that it stops immediately, if not nearly immediately? Any tips help thanks! 
Here is the code i'm using!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour{
public float speed;
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

void Start () 
{
rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{ 
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

rb2d.AddForce (movement * speed);
}
}
```

Comment: How are you computing position? It looks like it using some sort of "force", to me that says you movement deceleration is maybe not high enough?

Comment: That is the issue. I don't know how to increase the deceleration

Comment: Could you post the code that is actually calculating the position of the character?

Comment: I don't have the code with me because Unity Engine automatically does that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to increase the Deceleration. I scrapped my code and changed the mechanics so that the Character follows the mouse and moves forward with the "W" key or the up arrow. This smoothed the directional changes and made gameplay more enjoyable, as for the deceleration, I solved the problem by making the Linear Drag in the rigidbody2D inspector more than one and increasing the speed to make up for velocity loss.
Here is my code for future answer seekers!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour{
public float speed;
private Rigidbody2D rbtd;

void Start () 
{
    rbtd = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    var mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - mousePosition,
                                            Vector3.forward);

    transform.rotation = rot;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    rbtd.angularVelocity = 0;

    float input = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    rbtd.AddForce (gameObject.transform.up * speed * input);
}
}
```